# Why do I see EPDM rarely on pitched roofs

Tags: roofing

I rarely see EPDM used on pitched roofs, pitched roofs almost all use shingles instead.

I know on flat roofs EPDM is amazing. So why do you not see it on pitched roofs, is it due to the looks, that people prefer the look of shingles, or is there a technical reason? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe cost.  Shingles about the cheapest roofing for 15/20 year replacement time on pitched roofs.  People also like/are used to looking at shingles on roofs that they see.  If I have a choice, prefer metal roof, since it lasts longer.

Comment: Flat roofs have a lot of different needs to pitched roofs.  They need complete sealing from end to end.  Pitched roofs only need sealing from on top, water/rain runs down.

Comment: Cost and lack of need.

Answer (score 2):

On flat roofs, EPDM is not "amazing" so much as "required".  There aren't a lot of other good options for a flat roof.

Shingles have the merit of being "cheap", which makes them the darling of anyone who doesn't care about total life-cycle costs.  Such as anyone who imagines they'll be moving out of this house within 10 years, which is just about everybody.